# expireAfterSeconds doesnt work mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

Using Mongo 3.2

I set expireAfterSeconds to 3 days, because we do not need more then 3 days of data on this collection, but I can see in the db, that we still have data from a month ago. Is something configured wrong.

The info gather from db.runs.getIndexes()

```js
{
   "v" : 1,
   "key" : {
      "_id" : 1
    },
   "name" : "_id_",
   "ns" : "guardian.runs"
},
{
   "v" : 1,
   "key" : {
     "created" : 1
   },
   "name" : "created_1",
   "ns" : "guardian.runs",
   "background" : true,
   "expireAfterSeconds" : 259200
}
```

An entry that should be deleted:

```js
 [
   {
     "_id": "578c8aa25a3f72387073f2f0",
     "job_id": "573f62bf0e44a2796b6e9de1",
     "owner": null,
     "started": "2016-07-18T07:52:02.447Z",
     "ended": "2016-07-18T07:52:14.119Z",
     "status": "success",
     "result": {
       "success": [],
       "fail": [],
       "warning": []
     }
   }
]
```

Comment: added one of the entries

Comment: Your document doesn't have the `created` field that your TTL index references.

Comment: So if I change created to ended, it should work?

Comment: Yes, as long as `ended` is an actual Date data type and not just a string.

Answer (score 4):

Your document doesn't have the `created` field that your [TTL index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) references.

You need to add a `created` field to your docs with the time each doc is created, or change your TTL index to reference either `started` or `ended` instead (assuming those are actually Date values in the database and not just strings).